# How to implement Firebase notification API for user segment and topic using .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Following code I am using to send notification for single device and its working fine. But I want  send notification for particular group of client's 
Apps.

```
WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var objNotification = new
        {
            to = "Device_Token_Id",
            notification = new
            {
                title = "Notification Title",
                body = "Notification message"

            },

            priority = "high"
        };
        string jsonNotificationFormat = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objNotification);

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationFormat);

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "Server_Api_Key"));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "Sender_Id"));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String responseFromFirebaseServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                        Console.WriteLine(responseFromFirebaseServer);
                        Console.ReadLine();                                                  

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Please let me know if anyone know how to implement this api to send notification for particular group of user or to everyone.

Comment: How do you define a "group of users"?

Comment: Group of user means suppose there are 10 users have installed my app but I want to send common notification for only 5 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean user segments available in the Firebase console, then the answer is you cannot target them from the Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP API. At this point this is limited to the Firebase console.